# Connecting Oracle Primavera P6 EPPM (cloud) with Power BI

Tags: oracle, powerbi, azure-active-directory, powerquery, primavera

So, I am trying to connect to Oracle Primavera P6 EPPM application (which is hosted on Azure) though Power BI. But I a not sure how to connect to the underlying database tables of Primavera application. I know that we can use power bi REST API to connect to the Primavera application through `web.contents` method. But I am really not sure as to how to connect to the underlying database tables of Primavera by using `web.contents` method.

P.S : For those who want to down mark this question. Please note that I do not have any thing to
show as to what I have tried so far, Because, establishing a connection this app is the
first step. Please let me know if anyone has got any question incase if I can improvise this
question. Also I have searched everywhere on the web with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the application PSIX Extractor, you can choose required columns and filter data as like P6 professional filtering data from any P6 Database located in any cloud, On-Premise. you can export more than 500+ columns from the backend, and application is using P6 webservices in the backend, you don't need any developer to do any programming to extract data. if you know P6 then you can run the application. PSIX extractor works as integration tool as well

https://www.equivtech.com.au/Oracle-Primavera-P6-Extractor-Software.html